# Safari browser with Prevent cross-site tracking turn on, is it possible to get value of Local Storage in another subdomain

Tags: javascript, security, safari, local-storage

I am working on Safari version 13.
in [Preferences > Privacy] there is an option "Prevent cross-site tracking"

When this option is on, It will prevent cross-site tracking as its name implied, in order to protect the user's privacy.

However, it seems that local storage in different subdomains can't be shared as well.

For example, there are two subdomains here which are "auth" and "app"

auth.dev.domain.abc -> subdomain for authorization.
app.dev.domain.abc -> subdomain for main application.

At first, the user will log in at "auth.dev.domain.abc", once the user is logged in successfully, it will set a token in Local Storage, and the redirect to app.dev.domain.abc

## In case that "Prevent cross-site tracking" is **turned off**

1. Logged in at "auth.dev.domain.abc", accessToken is being set in Local Storage
2. Redirect to app.dev.domain.abc
3. currently at app.dev.domain.abc
4. When looking at Local Storage in safari by [Develop > Show web inspector > Storage]
   Under the section of Local Storage, we **can** see accessToken in auth.dev.domain.abc

## In case that "Prevent cross-site tracking" is **turned on**

1. Logged in at "auth.dev.domain.abc", accessToken is being set in Local Storage
2. Redirect to app.dev.domain.abc
3. currently at app.dev.domain.abc
4. When looking at Local Storage in safari by [Develop > Show web inspector > Storage]
   Under the section of Local Storage, we **can not** see accessToken in auth.dev.domain.abc

I don't know how to solve this issue, it seems that Safari considered different subdomain it as "cross-site"

What is the best way to work around this issue?

1. I have tried to use iframe from app.dev.domain.abc to auth.dev.domain.abc, but it seems that auth.dev.domain.abc in the iframe has no accessToken value in the local storage either.
2. Should i send the accessToken as and parameter in URL when redirect from "auth.dev.domain.abc" to "app.dev.domain.abc" and set local storage manually at "app.dev.domain.abc"?

Is there another solution that can make it work on this?

Comment: Any update on this one ? We seem to be impacted by it also

Comment: @Nexus I just switched from local storage to use cookie instead